# How to avoid warning message in wilcox.test

Tags: r

```
x <- c(9, 5, 9 ,10, 13, 8, 8, 13, 18, 30)
y <- c(10, 6, 9, 8, 11, 4, 1, 3, 3, 10)
wilcox.test(y,x, paired=TRUE,correct = FALSE)
```

Warning messages occurred when submit these codes. How to avoid warning message in wilcox.test.Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
suppressWarnings(wilcox.test(...))
```

or (better)

```
wilcox.test(...,exact=FALSE)
```

or

```
library(coin)
wilcoxsign_test(y~x,zero="Pratt")
```

Comment: (+1) Every day it gets harder to get answers up in time.  Haha.

Comment: @Bolker Thanks.How to compute V statistic and statistical test in wilcox.test. I can not find relevant materials about formula.

Comment: that's another question, possibly better for CrossValidated